# lib pthread: single threaded performance vs multithreaded

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, bioinformatics

(Note: I saw this post, tell me if that's the same problem: [C: performance of pthread, low than single thrad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874117))

I'm learning the **pthread** library. I wrote two versions of the same C program. The program takes a list of large [BAM files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samtools) and count the number of records  using the [samtools library](http://samtools.sourceforge.net/samtools/masterTOC.shtml).

Here is the **single-threaded** program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "bam.h"

/** maximum number of threads */
static const int MAX_COUNT_THREADS=4;

struct Param
    {
    char* filename;
    };


static void printCount(const char* filename,unsigned long count)
    {
    fprintf(stdout,"%s\t%ld\n",filename,count);
    }

static void* scan_bam(void* ptr)
    {
    unsigned long count=0;
    struct Param* params=(struct Param*)ptr;

    bamFile in=bam_open(params->filename, "r") ;
    bam_header_t *header= NULL;
    bam1_t *b=bam_init1();

    time_t rawtime;
    time ( &rawtime );

    fprintf(stderr,"STARTING : %s %s",params->filename,ctime(&rawtime));
    if(in==0)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot read %s.\n",params->filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    header= bam_header_read(in);
    while((bam_read1(in, b)) > 0)
        {
        ++count;
        }
    bam_destroy1(b);
    bam_header_destroy(header);
           bam_close(in);


    printCount(params->filename,count);

    time ( &rawtime );
    fprintf(stderr,"end for %s %s",params->filename,ctime(&rawtime));
    free(params);
    return NULL;
    }


int main(int argc,char** argv)
    {
    int optind=1;

    while(optind<argc)
    {
    struct Param* params=(struct Param*)malloc(sizeof(struct Param));

    if(params==0)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    params->filename=argv[optind++];
    scan_bam(params);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

and the **multi-threaded program**. This program can use up to 5 threads and uses a condition-lock to count the number of threads and tell the main program to start a new thread if needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "bam.h"

#define VERIFY_ZERO(a) do {if(a!=0) {\
    fprintf(stderr,"Test failed at %s line %d (ret=%d).\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,a);\
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
    }} while(0)



/** maximum number of threads */
static const int MAX_COUNT_THREADS=5;

struct Param
    {
    pthread_t thread;
    char* filename;
    };

struct GLOBALS {
    /** lock to print */
    pthread_mutex_t mutex_print;
    /** condition: wait for free thread */
    pthread_cond_t  accept_new_thread;
    /** condition lock */
    pthread_mutex_t  accept_new_thread_lock;
    /** number of running threads */
    int number_of_threads;
    };

static struct GLOBALS globals={
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    0
    };


static void printCount(const char* filename,unsigned long count)
    {
    int ret=pthread_mutex_lock(&globals.mutex_print);
    VERIFY_ZERO(ret);
    fprintf(stdout,"%s\t%ld\n",filename,count);
    ret=pthread_mutex_unlock(&globals.mutex_print);
    VERIFY_ZERO(ret);
    }

static void* scan_bam(void* ptr)
    {
    unsigned long count=0;
    struct Param* params=(struct Param*)ptr;
    bamFile in=bam_open(params->filename, "r") ;
    bam_header_t *header= NULL;
    bam1_t *b=bam_init1();
    time_t rawtime;
    time ( &rawtime );

    fprintf(stderr,"STARTING : %s %s",params->filename,ctime(&rawtime));
    if(in==0)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot read %s.\n",params->filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    header= bam_header_read(in);
    while((bam_read1(in, b)) > 0)
        {
        ++count;

        }
    bam_destroy1(b);
    bam_header_destroy(header);
           bam_close(in);


    printCount(params->filename,count);

    time ( &rawtime );
    fprintf(stderr,"end1 for %s %s",params->filename,ctime(&rawtime));
    pthread_mutex_lock( &globals.accept_new_thread_lock);
    globals.number_of_threads--;
    pthread_cond_signal(&globals.accept_new_thread);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&globals.accept_new_thread_lock);
    time ( &rawtime );
    fprintf(stderr,"end2 for %s %s",params->filename,ctime(&rawtime));
    free(params);
    return NULL;
    }


int main(int argc,char** argv)
    {
    int optind=1;

    while(optind<argc)
    {
    struct Param* params=(struct Param*)malloc(sizeof(struct Param));
    if(params==0)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&globals.accept_new_thread_lock);
    while (globals.number_of_threads > MAX_COUNT_THREADS)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&globals.accept_new_thread, &globals.accept_new_thread_lock);
        }
    globals.number_of_threads++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&globals.accept_new_thread_lock);

    params->filename=argv[optind++];
    fprintf(stderr,"creating %s\n",params->filename);
    pthread_create (&(params->thread), NULL, scan_bam,params);
    pthread_detach(params->thread);

    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&globals.accept_new_thread_lock);
    while (globals.number_of_threads > 0)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&globals.accept_new_thread, &globals.accept_new_thread_lock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&globals.accept_new_thread_lock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&globals.accept_new_thread);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

#### Compile and run the multi-threaded program

```
gcc -O3 -Wall jeter.c -pthread -I/usr/local/package/samtools-0.1.18 -L/usr/local/package/samtools-0.1.18/  -lbam -lz
$ time (find .// -name "*recal.bam" | grep Item1[0-9] | xargs ./a.out )
creating ./Item10/recal.bam
creating ./Item11/recal.bam
creating ./Item12/recal.bam
creating ./Item13/recal.bam
creating ./Item14/recal.bam
creating ./Item15/recal.bam
STARTING : ./Item10/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:12:48 2012
STARTING : ./Item11/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:12:48 2012
STARTING : ./Item12/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:12:48 2012
STARTING : ./Item14/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:12:48 2012
STARTING : ./Item13/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:12:48 2012
STARTING : ./Item15/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:12:48 2012
./Item10/recal.bam    185784310
end1 for ./Item10/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:38:16 2012
end2 for ./Item10/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:38:16 2012
creating ./Item16/recal.bam
STARTING : ./Item16/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:38:16 2012
./Item11/recal.bam    204408906
end1 for ./Item11/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:41:52 2012
end2 for ./Item11/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:41:52 2012
creating ./Item17/recal.bam
STARTING : ./Item17/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:41:52 2012
./Item12/recal.bam    207766317
end1 for ./Item12/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:42:17 2012
end2 for ./Item12/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:42:17 2012
creating ./Item18/recal.bam
STARTING : ./Item18/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:42:17 2012
./Item15/recal.bam    224957522
end1 for ./Item15/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:44:54 2012
end2 for ./Item15/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:44:54 2012
creating ./Item19/recal.bam
STARTING : ./Item19/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:44:54 2012
./Item13/recal.bam    224548326
end1 for ./Item13/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:45:32 2012
end2 for ./Item13/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:45:32 2012
./Item14/recal.bam    241267346
end1 for ./Item14/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:48:28 2012
end2 for ./Item14/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 15:48:28 2012
./Item16/recal.bam    227446579
end1 for ./Item16/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:12:15 2012
end2 for ./Item16/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:12:15 2012
./Item17/recal.bam    215307379
end1 for ./Item17/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:13:05 2012
end2 for ./Item17/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:13:05 2012
./Item18/recal.bam    225914723
end1 for ./Item18/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:13:48 2012
end2 for ./Item18/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:13:48 2012
./Item19/recal.bam    225509630
end1 for ./Item19/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:14:06 2012
end2 for ./Item19/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:14:06 2012
```

.

```
real    61m17.560s
user    66m0.476s
sys    4m5.980s
```

#### Compile and run the single-threaded program

```
$ gcc -O3 -Wall jeter2.c -I/usr/local/package/samtools-0.1.18 -L/usr/local/package/samtools-0.1.18/  -lbam -lz

time (find .// -name "*recal.bam" | grep Item1[0-9] | xargs ./a.out )
STARTING : ./Item10/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:15:25 2012
./Item10/recal.bam    185784310
end for ./Item10/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:20:43 2012
STARTING : ./Item11/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:20:43 2012
./Item11/recal.bam    204408906
end for ./Item11/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:26:20 2012
STARTING : ./Item12/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:26:20 2012
./Item12/recal.bam    207766317
end for ./Item12/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:31:56 2012
STARTING : ./Item13/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:31:56 2012
./Item13/recal.bam    224548326
end for ./Item13/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:38:05 2012
STARTING : ./Item14/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:38:05 2012
./Item14/recal.bam    241267346
end for ./Item14/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:44:59 2012
STARTING : ./Item15/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:44:59 2012
./Item15/recal.bam    224957522
end for ./Item15/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:50:56 2012
STARTING : ./Item16/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:50:56 2012
./Item16/recal.bam    227446579
end for ./Item16/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:58:07 2012
STARTING : ./Item17/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 16:58:07 2012
./Item17/recal.bam    215307379
end for ./Item17/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 17:04:58 2012
STARTING : ./Item18/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 17:04:58 2012
./Item18/recal.bam    225914723
end for ./Item18/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 17:11:31 2012
STARTING : ./Item19/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 17:11:31 2012
./Item19/recal.bam    225509630
end for ./Item19/recal.bam Tue Dec 18 17:18:19 2012
```

.

```
real    62m54.503s
user    53m39.529s
sys    3m44.580s
```

both programs have been running for ~1H00. So the MT program was running slower than the other. Why ? Is it possible to speed-up that code ?

Comment: The problem here is probably the filesystem. In the threaded program you try to read several files at the same time, probably from the same disk, which is not very efficient.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I wish someone would generate some actual stats for this kind of disk operation. Posters keep saying that using multiple threads will either not help or actually slow things down, but I've seen no numbers/graphs.  It would be nice if someone actually tried this with one local spinner, a local SSD and a networked disk, (and maybe some combos).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like I/O operations (reading from files) dominate in your program, so it's quite likely you won't get much benefit from threading, no matter how well it is done.

Also note that the multithreaded variant is in fact a little bit faster; you need to compare *real time*. The *user time* is bigger due to multithreading, as it sums up the time spent in user mode by all threads. Same for *kernel time*.

Comment: +1, though I will add that a much greater speedup may be achieved if the files are on different disks, especially notoriously latency-ridden and disconnection-prone networked disks.  Also, I wonder what the effect would be if the app was redesigned to pool the threads and avoid the miserable continual create/terminate/destroy of threads?

Answer (score 3):

First I want to make something clear:

**Multi threaded does NOT necessarily mean your program will run faster!**

It can mean that, but that *depends* on how parallel your program can really execute.

I see in your MT code that you are waiting on condition variables, that means there's a possible point of contention there, and that there is no real parallelism going on here.

Real speedup by threading is gained actually, when your threads can each do a chunck of work on which they do not have to wait on other threads for.  If everything they can be done totally independently,  you **may** get some speedup.

That speedup then also depends on things like false sharing, which is (assuming a multi core CPU), if you have some array in memory and thread A needs element 2 in that array, while another thread B also running needs element 4 in that array, and elements are sizeof(int) for example, then you'd know that you get caching issues.  The caches will need to be updated each time either thread does a write to the arrays. Assuming cache lines are 64k.  This is false sharing. This can cause quite significant slow downs.

There's other reasons too that your MT program won't speed up over your single threaded one.  The ultimate question you should ask is:

*Can I make the threads do a piece of work that has no dependencies on any other thread?*

From all the waiting you are making your threads do, it seems not.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your useful answer. I'll validate the best answer later.